# Saxon SQL extension is not working with XSLT on Saxon 9.8.0.8 PE or EE

Tags: sql, xslt, saxon

Currently i am trying to make a simple sql connection on Oracle DB; by using Saxon SQL extension described in examples.

But my stylesheet is not compiled on Oxygen XML Editor(v20) which is using Saxon 9.8.0.8 as default,and it doesn't give me any trace what to do :

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:bsh="http://bsh-partner.com/PICenter" 
        xmlns:e="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" 
        xmlns:sql="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        exclude-result-prefixes="saxon e xs bsh xsd xsi xsl">    
    <xsl:param name="jdbc.driver"   as="xsd:string" select="'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'" />
        <xsl:param name="jdbc.database" as="xsd:string" select="'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/PDPP.MCH.BSHG.COM'" />
        <xsl:param name="jdbc.user" as="xsd:string" select="'dbuser'" />
        <xsl:param name="jdbc.pass" as="xsd:string" select="'dbpassword'" />
        <xsl:variable name="sql.conn" as="java:java.sql.Connection" xmlns:java="http://saxon.sf.net/java-type">
            <sql:connect driver="{$jdbc.driver}" database="{$jdbc.database}" user="{$jdbc.user}" password="{$jdbc.pass}">
                <xsl:fallback>
                    <xsl:message terminate="yes">SQL extenstions are not installed</xsl:message>
                </xsl:fallback>
            </sql:connect>
        </xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/e:Envelope/e:Body">
        <log>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </log>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently variable $sql.conn gives the error of :

```
Required item type of value of variable $sql.conn is Q{http://saxon.sf.net/java-type}java.sql.Connection; supplied value (<sql:connect {(attr{driver=...}, ...)}/>) has item type element()
```

So i can't try how this extension works in my stylesheet, any ideas or support would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was rather specific to set about some configuration on Oxygen regarding to Saxon processor, firstly as it is explained on documentations,i need to make specific Saxon configuration on my transformation scenario by reffering to that xml below

```
<configuration xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration" edition="EE">
  <global allowExternalFunctions="true" versionOfXml="1.0"/>
  <xslt>
    <extensionElement namespace="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
      factory="net.sf.saxon.option.sql.SQLElementFactory"/>
  </xslt>
</configuration>
```

Secondly, i've put ojdb6.jar into directory `$oxygen-installation-dir/lib` then restarted Oxygen and extension get worked without any compile errors!

Answer (score 1):

Declare `extension-element-prefixes="sql"` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#designating-extension-namespace), otherwise no processor can recognise those elements as extensions.